# Python 3.x tkinter Place Entries on top of eachother

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Gmail App")
def login():
    L1 = Label(root, text="Email")
    L1.pack( side = LEFT)
    E1 = Entry(root, bd =5)
    E1.pack(side = LEFT)

    L1 = Label(root, text="Password")
    L1.pack( side = RIGHT)
    E1 = Entry(root, bd =5)
    E1.pack(side = RIGHT)
login()
root.mainloop()
```

I have this code, and I`d like to place the 'email' entry above the 'password' entry. How might I do this? Thanks

Im very new to tkinter. . . where might i learn better?

Comment: `side='top'` or `side='bottom'` places objects in a vertical arrangement.

Comment: thanks :) it helps

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use grid layout manager not pack.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Gmail App")
def login():
    L1 = Label(root, text="Email")
    E1 = Entry(root, bd=5)

    L2 = Label(root, text="Password")
    E2 = Entry(root, bd=5)
    L1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    L2.grid(row=3, column=0)
    E1.grid(row=2, column=0)
    E2.grid(row=4, column=0)


login()
root.mainloop()
```

And this tutorial will be helpful for newer:
https://pythonprogramming.net/python-3-tkinter-basics-tutorial/

Comment: does it have a way to add a Y scrollbar to a text entry?